# Conta em jquery não funciona

Tags: jquery

Olá, estou tentando montar este codigo, porem ele não esta funcionando corretamente, se possivel analisar pois não achei os erros...

```
<script src="jscripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
function AtualizaMensalidade(tributacao, tipo_emp, fat_mes, qt_func, bcos_contas, LabelID)
    {
        tributacao = $('#tributacao').val();
        tipo_emp = $('#tipo_emp').val();
        fat_mes = $('#fat_mes').val();
        qt_func = $('#qt_func').val();
        bcos_contas = $('#bcos_contas').val();

        var MesCalc = (qt_func * 20) + tipo_emp + fat_mes + tributacao;

        if (isNaN(MesCalc)) {
            document.getElementById(LabelID).innerHTML = "- -";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(LabelID).innerHTML = formatDinheiro(MesCalc, "R$");
        }
    }

    function formatDinheiro(n, currency) {
        return currency + " " + n.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,");
    }

</script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-4 alinha">
            <label>Tipo de atividade</label>
            <select id="tributacao" name="tributacao" class="form-control input" onchange="Mensalidade(this.value,'tributacao','tipo_emp','fat_mes','qt_func','bcos_contas','AtualizaMensalidade')" />>
            <option value="0">Escolha</option>
            <option value="49.90">MEI</option>
            <option value="219">Simples Nacional</option>
            <option value="319">Lucro Presumido</option>
            <option value="2500">Lucro Real</option>

        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 alinha">
            <label>Tipo de atividade</label>
            <select id="tipo_emp" name="tipo_emp" class="form-control input"  onchange="Mensalidade(this.value,'tributacao','tipo_emp','fat_mes','qt_func','bcos_contas','AtualizaMensalidade')">
            <option value="0">Escolha</option>
            <option value="30">Serviços</option>
            <option value="150">Industrial</option>
            <option value="80">Comercial</option>
            <option value="110">Serviços e Comercio</option>

            </select>   

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 alinha">
        faturamento mes<br>
        <input type="number" id="fat_mes" name="fat_mes" class="form-control input" onchange="Mensalidade(this.value,'tributacao','tipo_emp','fat_mes','qt_func','bcos_contas','AtualizaMensalidade')">
    </div>
</div><br>
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="col-md-4 alinha">
        <label>Numero de Funcionarios</label>
        <input type="number" id="qt_func" name="qt_func" class="form-control input" onchange="Mensalidade(this.value,'tributacao','tipo_emp','fat_mes','qt_func','bcos_contas','AtualizaMensalidade')">
    </div>      
    <div class="col-md-4 alinha">
        </label>Quantidade de contas</label>
        <input type="number" id="bcos_contas" name="bcos_contas" value="0" class="form-control input" onchange="Mensalidade(this.value,'tributacao','tipo_emp','fat_mes','qt_func','bcos_contas','AtualizaMensalidade')">
    </div>

<div class="alinha">Resultado: R$ <span id="AtualizaMensalidade">---</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Facilitaria se mencionasse o que não está  funcionando corretamente!

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt! Leia em [Como perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) e [mcve](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para saber como elaborar uma pergunta de facil compreensao e assim poder ser ajudado. Por exemplo, qual o erro que você está tendo no seu código, o que está funcionando?

Comment: Vinicius explique melhor para nós, o que você esperava que acontecesse e não acontece e o que você já tentou fazer, se este código ai é seu ou ja estava em produção quando você pegou o projeto...Assim poderemos te ajudar melhor meu amigo. O @Sergio já publicou uma resposta que pode resolver seu problema abaixo.

Comment: o erro que tenho é que não aparece o valor total no final, pois sou novo nessa linguagem... porem sei que é uma conta simples de se fazer, mais estou perdido....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando tens, por exemplo

```
<select id="tributacao" name="tributac... etc
    <option value="219">Simples Nacional</option>
```

e vais buscar o valor da opção selecionada com `tributacao = $('#tributacao').val();` isso vai retornarte uma *String* e não um *Number*. Ou seja retorna "219" em vez de 219. Tens de utilizar `parseInt` ou neste caso como tens valores com casas decimais `parseFloat`.

Não relacionado com o teu problema, mas uma sugestão:

na tua função tens: `function AtualizaMensalidade(tributacao, tipo_emp, fat_mes, qt_func, bcos_contas, LabelID) {` mas parece-me que não precisas desses argumentos. Será uma maneira de evitar declarar variáveis? Nesse caso desaconse-lho. Dificulta a leitura de código. Eu faria assim:

```js
var label = document.getElementById('AtualizaMensalidade');
['tributacao', 'tipo_emp', 'fat_mes', 'qt_func', 'bcos_contas'].forEach(function(id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    el.addEventListener('change', Mensalidade)
});

function Mensalidade() {
    var qt_func = parseFloat(document.getElementById('qt_func').value);
    var MesCalc = (qt_func * 20) + ['tributacao', 'tipo_emp', 'fat_mes'].reduce(function(total, id) {
        var val = document.getElementById(id).value;
        return total + parseFloat(val);
    }, 0);
    label.innerHTML = isNaN(MesCalc) ? "- -" : formatDinheiro(MesCalc, "R$");
}

function formatDinheiro(n, currency) {
    return currency + " " + n.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,");
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-4 alinha">
        <label>Tipo de atividade</label>
        <select id="tributacao" name="tributacao" class="form-control input">
            <option value="0">Escolha</option>
            <option value="49.90">MEI</option>
            <option value="219">Simples Nacional</option>
            <option value="319">Lucro Presumido</option>
            <option value="2500">Lucro Real</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 alinha">
        <label>Tipo de atividade</label>
        <select id="tipo_emp" name="tipo_emp" class="form-control input">
            <option value="0">Escolha</option>
            <option value="30">Serviços</option>
            <option value="150">Industrial</option>
            <option value="80">Comercial</option>
            <option value="110">Serviços e Comercio</option>

        </select>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 alinha">
        faturamento mes
        <br>
        <input type="number" id="fat_mes" name="fat_mes" class="form-control input">
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-4 alinha">
        <label>Numero de Funcionarios</label>
        <input type="number" id="qt_func" name="qt_func" class="form-control input">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 alinha">
        <label>Quantidade de contas</label>
        <input type="number" id="bcos_contas" name="bcos_contas" value="0" class="form-control input">
    </div>

    <div class="alinha">Resultado: <span id="AtualizaMensalidade">---</span></div>
</div>
```

Não vejo na tua função onde usas `bcos_contas = $('#bcos_contas').val();`, por isso retirei do meu exemplo.
`

Comment: a parte do bcos_contas ainda não tinha aplicado, porem o valor não aparece em baixo o resultado, sou novo em jquery e to apanhando muito.

Comment: @ViniciusNakamura vou juntar uma versão melhor. 1 min.

Comment: @ViniciusNakamura olha de novo para a resposta. Bem mais simples... sem jQuery e mais simples no HTML e JavaScript.

Comment: Muito obrigado, agora tenho que ler mais e me aprofundar mais nessa linguagem.